# Custom SQL query to insert results of a SELECT into a table in Spring Boot JPA Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a spring boot project using JPA hibernate.

I'm trying to make a custom query that inserts the results of a `select` into a table. How would I do that?

This is my SQL query:

```
INSERT INTO aggregateTable

  (
    SELECT
      avgSalesA,
      avgSalesB,
      salesMade,
      tableA.employeeid
    FROM

      (
        SELECT
          avg(sales) as avgSalesA,
          count(salesMadeDaily) as SalesMadeTotal,
          employeeid
        FROM companyA
        GROUP BY employeeid
      ) tableA

    INNER JOIN

    (
      SELECT
        avg(sales) as avgSalesB,
        employeeid
      FROM companyB
      GROUP BY employeeid
    ) tableB

    ON tableA.employeeid = tableB.employeeid
  )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply use JPA:

```
entityManager.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO aggregateTable (Select avgSalesA, avgSalesB, 
                             salesMade, tableA.employeeid FROM 
                             (SELECT avg(sales) as avgSalesA, count(salesMadeDaily) as 
                             SalesMadeTotal, employeeid FROM companyA GROUP BY 
                             employeeid) tableA INNER JOIN (SELECT 
                             avg(sales) as avgSalesB, employeeid FROM companyB group 
                             by employeeid) 
                             tableB ON tableA.employeeid = tableB.employeeid)");
```

Or if you use Spring Data repositories

```
@Modifying
@Query("<your insert query", nativeQuery=true)
public int insert();
```